# Count if condition is met Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have the following spreadsheet.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q8ZaPMNuWqoLCykxV8W2YgP6SDD8Lv0TuGbqBJGEFwg/edit?usp=sharing)

I need a script to count each agent email address (overall and based on client). I am struggling with arrays. I am new on scripting so still learning. So, on the Reports tab I need to know how many calls an agent made, then how many calls he made for Client 1, Client 2 and so on, how many appointments made - overall and for each client. I don't want to use `=COUNTIFS()` as this will be dynamic and in time there will be new agents.

I will make a script to get unique emails and paste it into a table and from there I need this script to count.

In the shared file I have my script, but I stuck there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Build and Load Everything All At Once

I added a few more ranges to your reports sheet so that I could display all of the client data. The client names and agent emails have to be there because they are used as inputs in my data arrays and objects.

Here's the code:

```
function reportSummary()//This is final output
{
  var br='<br />';
  var agentA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var clientAgents=emailAddressAssociatedWithEachClient();
  var agentClients=clientsAssociatedWithEachEmail();
  var callsByAgent=callsMadeByAgentTotal();
  var callsByAgentToClient=callsMadeByAgentToClient();
  var apptsByAgent=apptsBookedByAgentTotal();
  var apptsByAgentForClient=apptsBookedByAgentForClient();

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rptSh=ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
  var rgA=["A2:C6","A8:C12","A14:C18"];
  for(var i=0;i<rgA.length;i++)
  {
    var rg1=rptSh.getRange(rgA[i]);
    var vA1=rg1.getValues();
    vA1[2][1]=callsByAgentToClient[vA1[2][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[3][1]=callsByAgentToClient[vA1[3][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[4][1]=callsByAgentToClient[vA1[4][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[2][2]=apptsByAgentForClient[vA1[2][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[3][2]=apptsByAgentForClient[vA1[3][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[4][2]=apptsByAgentForClient[vA1[4][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    rg1.setValues(vA1);
  }
  var rg2=rptSh.getRange('E2:H6');
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  vA2[2][1]=callsByAgent[vA2[2][0]];
  vA2[3][1]=callsByAgent[vA2[3][0]];
  vA2[4][1]=callsByAgent[vA2[4][0]];
  vA2[2][2]=apptsByAgent[vA2[2][0]];
  vA2[3][2]=apptsByAgent[vA2[3][0]];
  vA2[4][2]=apptsByAgent[vA2[4][0]];
  rg2.setValues(vA2);


  /*
  var s='<strong>Clients Contacted by Agent:</strong>';
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    s+=br + '<span style="color:#ff0000">' + agentA[i] + '</span>';
    for(var j=0;j<agentClients[agentA[i]].length;j++)
    {
       s+=br + agentClients[agentA[i]][j];
    }

  }
  s+=br + br + '<strong>Agents who Contacted Client:</strong>';
  for(var i=0;i<clientA.length;i++)
  {
    s+=br + '<span style="color:#ff0000">' + clientA[i] + '</span>';
    for(var j=0;j<clientAgents[clientA[i]].length;j++)
    {
      s+=br + clientAgents[clientA[i]][j];
    }
  }
  s+=br + br + '<strong>Calls made by Agents:</strong>';
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    s+=br + Utilities.formatString('<br />%s = %s',agentA[i],callsByAgent[agentA[i]]);
  }
  s+=br + br + '<strong>Calls made by Agents to Client:</strong>';
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<clientA.length;j++)
    {
      s+=br + Utilities.formatString('<br />%s<br />%s<br />%s',agentA[i],clientA[j],callsByAgentToClient[agentA[i]][clientA[j]])
    }
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Report Summary');
  */
}




function uniqueItemArray(column) 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cntSh=ss.getSheetByName('Count');
  var cntRg=cntSh.getDataRange();
  var vA=cntRg.getValues();
  var uiA=[];
  for(var i=2;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    if(uiA.indexOf(String(vA[i][column-1]).trim())==-1)
    {
      uiA.push(vA[i][column-1]);
    }
  }
  return uiA;
}

function emailAddressAssociatedWithEachClient()
{
  var agentEmailsA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cntSh=ss.getSheetByName('Count');
  var cntRg=cntSh.getDataRange();
  var vA=cntRg.getValues();
  var cEO=[];
  for(var i=0;i<clientA.length;i++)
  {
    var ceA=[];
    for(var j=2;j<vA.length;j++)
    {
      if(ceA.indexOf(String(vA[j][3]).trim())==-1 && String(vA[j][4]).trim()==clientA[i])
      {
        ceA.push(vA[j][3]);
      }
    }
    cEO[clientA[i]]=ceA;
  }
  /*
  for(var n=0;n<clientA.length;n++)
  {
    Logger.log(clientA[n] + '\n' + cEO[clientA[n]]);
  }
  */
  return cEO;
}

function clientsAssociatedWithEachEmail()
{
  var agentEmailsA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cntSh=ss.getSheetByName('Count');
  var cntRg=cntSh.getDataRange();
  var vA=cntRg.getValues();
  var cEO=[];
  for(var i=0;i<agentEmailsA.length;i++)
  {
    var ceA=[];
    for(var j=2;j<vA.length;j++)
    {
      if(ceA.indexOf(String(vA[j][4]).trim())==-1 && String(vA[j][3]).trim()==agentEmailsA[i])
      {
        ceA.push(vA[j][4]);
      }
    }
    cEO[agentEmailsA[i]]=ceA;
  }
  /*
  for(var n=0;n<agentEmailsA.length;n++)
  {
    Logger.log(agentEmailsA[n] + '\n' + cEO[agentEmailsA[n]]);
  }
  */
  return cEO;
}

function callsMadeByAgentTotal()
{
  var agentA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cntSh=ss.getSheetByName('Count');
  var cntRg=cntSh.getDataRange();
  var vA=cntRg.getValues();
  var callsByAgent=[];
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    var cnt=0;
    for(var j=2;j<vA.length;j++)
    {
      if(vA[j][3]==agentA[i])
      {
        cnt++;
      }
    }
    callsByAgent[agentA[i]]=cnt;
  }
  /*
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
     Logger.log('\n%s\n%s',agentA[i],callsByAgent[agentA[i]]);
  }
  var s=Logger.getLog().replace(/^.+:/gm,'').replace(/\n/g,'<br />');
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Calls By Agent')
  */
  return callsByAgent;
}

function callsMadeByAgentToClient()
{
  var agentA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cntSh=ss.getSheetByName('Count');
  var cntRg=cntSh.getDataRange();
  var vA=cntRg.getValues();
  var callsByAgentToClient=[];
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    callsByAgentToClient[agentA[i]]=[];
    for(var k=0;k<clientA.length;k++)
    {
      var cnt=0;
      for(var j=2;j<vA.length;j++)
      {
        if(vA[j][3]==agentA[i] && vA[j][4]==clientA[k])
        {
          cnt++;
        }
      }
      callsByAgentToClient[agentA[i]][clientA[k]]=cnt;
    }
  }
  /*
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<clientA.length;j++)
    {
      Logger.log('\n%s\n%s\n%s',agentA[i],clientA[j],callsByAgentToClient[agentA[i]][clientA[j]]);
    }
  }
  var s=Logger.getLog().replace(/^.+:/gm,'').replace(/\n/g,'<br />');
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Calls By Agent To Client')
  */
   return callsByAgentToClient;
}

function apptsBookedByAgentTotal()
{
  var agentA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cntSh=ss.getSheetByName('Count');
  var cntRg=cntSh.getDataRange();
  var vA=cntRg.getValues();
  var apptsByAgent=[];
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    var cnt=0;
    for(var j=2;j<vA.length;j++)
    {
      if(vA[j][3]==agentA[i] && vA[j][5])
      {
        cnt++;
      }
    }
    apptsByAgent[agentA[i]]=cnt;
  }
  /*
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
     Logger.log('\n%s\n%s',agentA[i],apptsByAgent[agentA[i]]);
  }
  var s=Logger.getLog().replace(/^.+:/gm,'').replace(/\n/g,'<br />');
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Calls By Agent')
  */
  return apptsByAgent;
}

function apptsBookedByAgentForClient()
{
  var agentA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cntSh=ss.getSheetByName('Count');
  var cntRg=cntSh.getDataRange();
  var vA=cntRg.getValues();
  var apptsByAgentForClient=[];
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    apptsByAgentForClient[agentA[i]]=[];
    for(var k=0;k<clientA.length;k++)
    {
      var cnt=0;
      for(var j=2;j<vA.length;j++)
      {
        if(vA[j][3]==agentA[i] && vA[j][4]==clientA[k] && vA[j][5])
        {
          cnt++;
        }
      }
      apptsByAgentForClient[agentA[i]][clientA[k]]=cnt;
    }
  }
  /*
  for(var i=0;i<agentA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<clientA.length;j++)
    {
      Logger.log('\n%s\n%s\n%s',agentA[i],clientA[j],apptsByAgentForClient[agentA[i]][clientA[j]]);
    }
  }
  var s=Logger.getLog().replace(/^.+:/gm,'').replace(/\n/g,'<br />');
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Calls By Agent To Client')
  */
   return apptsByAgentForClient;
}
```

And here's an image of my reports sheet:

[image]

Check Out reportSummaryNew() it creates a new sheet generates the report body and fills in all of the data.  A separate function called buildReport() does the report building and returns an array of ranges for reportSummaryNew().

```
function buildReport()
{
   var br='<br />';
  var agentA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.insertSheet();
  var shName=sh.getName();
  sh.activate();
  var rngA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<=clientA.length;i++)
  {
    rngA[i]=sh.getRange(i*(agentA.length + 2) + 1,1,agentA.length + 2,3);
    var vA=rngA[i].getValues();
    if(i!=clientA.length)
    {
      vA[0][0]=clientA[i];
    }
    else
    {
      vA[0][0]='All';
    }
    vA[1][1]='Calls Made';
    vA[1][2]='Appointments Booked';
    for(var j=0;j<agentA.length;j++)
    {
      vA[j+2][0]=agentA[j];
    }
    rngA[i].setValues(vA);
  }
  return rngA;
}

function reportSummaryNew()
{
  var br='<br />';
  var agentA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var clientAgents=emailAddressAssociatedWithEachClient();
  var agentClients=clientsAssociatedWithEachEmail();
  var callsByAgent=callsMadeByAgentTotal();
  var callsByAgentToClient=callsMadeByAgentToClient();
  var apptsByAgent=apptsBookedByAgentTotal();
  var apptsByAgentForClient=apptsBookedByAgentForClient();
  var rngA=buildReport();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rptSh=ss.getActiveSheet();

  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length-1;i++)
  {
    var rg1=rngA[i];
    var vA1=rg1.getValues();
    vA1[2][1]=callsByAgentToClient[vA1[2][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[3][1]=callsByAgentToClient[vA1[3][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[4][1]=callsByAgentToClient[vA1[4][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[2][2]=apptsByAgentForClient[vA1[2][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[3][2]=apptsByAgentForClient[vA1[3][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    vA1[4][2]=apptsByAgentForClient[vA1[4][0]][vA1[0][0]];
    rg1.setValues(vA1);
  }
  var rg2=rngA[rngA.length-1];
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  vA2[2][1]=callsByAgent[vA2[2][0]];
  vA2[3][1]=callsByAgent[vA2[3][0]];
  vA2[4][1]=callsByAgent[vA2[4][0]];
  vA2[2][2]=apptsByAgent[vA2[2][0]];
  vA2[3][2]=apptsByAgent[vA2[3][0]];
  vA2[4][2]=apptsByAgent[vA2[4][0]];
  rg2.setValues(vA2);
}
```

Here's what the new Generated Report Looks Like:

[image]

If you wish to be able to format the report you can run buildReport and take one of the sections and move it to the upper left corner A1:C5 and format it any way you like and then replace this line `var rngA=buildReport()` in reportSummaryNew() with this `var rngA=buildReport1()` yes just add a 1 between the 't' and '('. The buildReport1() function will copy the format from Format!A1:A5 so you can change the format easily any time you want just by formatting the contents of the sheet named 'Format';

Here's buildReport1()

```
function buildReport1()
{
  var br='<br />';
  var agentA=uniqueItemArray(4);
  var clientA=uniqueItemArray(5);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var trng=ss.getSheetByName('Format').getRange("A1:C5");
  var sh=ss.insertSheet();
  var shName=sh.getName();
  sh.activate();
  var rngA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<=clientA.length;i++)
  {
    rngA[i]=sh.getRange(i*(agentA.length + 2) + 1,1,agentA.length + 2,3);
    var vA=rngA[i].getValues();
    trng.copyTo(rngA[i],{formatOnly:true});
    if(i!=clientA.length)
    {
      vA[0][0]=clientA[i];
    }
    else
    {
      vA[0][0]='All';
    }
    vA[1][1]='Calls Made';
    vA[1][2]='Appointments Booked';
    for(var j=0;j<agentA.length;j++)
    {
      vA[j+2][0]=agentA[j];
    }
    rngA[i].setValues(vA);
  }
  return rngA;
}
```

And here's and image of how I formatted it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: It was really A lot of fun.